# Weighted table probabilities without replacement

Tags: probability, weighted-data

I'm trying to recall some statistical maths and could do with a little asisstance.

I'm dealing with a weighted table, and I want to work out the probability of drawing certain values with no order, considering that once a value has been drawn it can no longer be selected.

| Name | Weight |
| --- | --- |
| A | 6 |
| B | 6 |
| C | 6 |
| D | 4 |
| E | 4 |
| F | 4 |
| G | 4 |
| H | 4 |
| I | 3 |
| J | 3 |

Now I can recall that to work out if at least one will be selected I can do the inverse binomial to work out the case when 0 will get selected

X = number of times for a specific outcome within n tries

P = probability calculated

N = number of tries

p = probability of success in a single try

q = probability of failure in a single try

P(X) = (N/X) * p^x * q^(n-x)

so for example for I found at least once with 3 tries it would be

P(>0) = 1 - P(0) = 1 - (3/0) * (3/44)^0 * (41/44)^3

P(>0) = 1 - 1 * 1 * ~0.81

P(>0) = ~0.19

but I don't think that takes into account that if I select one, then the entire group would be removed.
So therefore I could look at the case that only one is selected in x tries, but I'm unsure of how to look at getting multiple values.

Say I wanted to work out the probability getting I and J, in 4 tries, in any order, considering every try would remove one of the groups from the table. Would the binomial support that, I assume not, is there a nice workaround or does it just get messy?

p.s. I'm not really a maths person so sorry for the formatting of the question

Comment: Please explain what the weights mean.  In particular, when (say) an "A" is drawn, is it gone forever, or is its weight just reduced from 6 to 5?

Comment: When A is drawn it is removed forever, the weights contribute to the probability of it being drawn. So as the total number of weights is 44, A has a probability of 6/44 to be drawn. Once A is drawn the pool will shrink, and the chance of drawing B will be 6/38.